# Choosing a source control system: logical next steps after VSS

Tags: svn, git, version-control, visual-sourcesafe

I've been using Git for the past few months and love it.

I looked into how to host it in a corporate environment. Considering a 10 person team who use Visual SourceSafe, programming in Coldfusion, Powerbuilder, PHP and a bit of .NET, I found, to my surprise, that the Git 'server' tooling is still fairly rudimentary.

[Git in a company - hosting own server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761054/git-in-a-company-hosting-own-server)

**Question** Apart from SVN, what other source control options would be a logical next step after VSS?  Paid options are fine.

Something with nice tooling, that isn't scary would be great :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "Git 'server' tooling is fairly rudimentary'?  There are both git access management tools like Gitosis and (younger) Gitolite, git hosting solutions like GitHub:FI, Gitorious, Girocco or InDefero, and review boards such as Gerrit (see article on Gerrit at LWN.net)?

Comment: See Stuart Ellis answer below too for pay tools for server software...

Comment: Isn't using VSS so scary that anything else is better than using it?

Comment: You survived VSS for there to BE an after? I'm impressed :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perforce (non-free) offers a lot of features and tools. I heard Google uses it. Perforce offers more advanced branching and merging capabilities than SVN.

Comment: Also a good one. I heard Microsoft used it instead of VSS, which is almost laughable. :)

Comment: @Sergei: To be fair, VSS hasn't been maintained for almost 10 years now. If they were still using it I'd be surprised.

Answer (score 4):

There are several Git hosting services that provide Web interfaces and integrated project management, and some of them are targeted at corporate development teams. [ProjectLocker](http://www.projectlocker.com/) and [Codebase](http://wwww.codebasehq.com/) are two of these. Both [Assembla](http://wwww.assembla.com/) and [Github](http://fi.github.com/) offer a installable version of their server software, so that you can run a private instance of their service.

Answer (score 3):

I think Team Foundation Server would be the next logical step up from Visual Source Safe. You can also check out [SourceGear Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/vs/subversion/) as another alternative to VSS.

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer (as I'm an advocate of SVN myself), but take a look at Wikipedia's entries for [List of revision control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software) and [Comparison of revision control software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software). It will give you something to investigate while you wait for answers here and you might find something little-known that just fits the bill for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Team foundation server, I believe is one that has been tossed around.

Comment: Cheers!  Would be nice.. a wee bit pricey.  Althought I did hear rumours of a community edition.

Answer (score 0):

[TFS Basic](http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/archive/2009/10/01/tfs-2010-for-sourcesafe-users.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I'd go with SVN or CVS.  Big community and lots of tools and documentation.

Comment: Question says 'apart from SVN'. I'd also assume that if he's rejected SVN then he'll reject CVS as well.

Comment: I don't mind SVN at all.. quite nice with TortoiseSVN :-)  Just trying to get a feel if I've missed anything obvious.

Comment: SVN is the best "server" based source control system out there, imo.